# `SInt * SInt` became `UInt * SInt` in chisel

Tags: chisel, chiseltest

I'm writing a convolution neural network accelerator. In the conv unit, I choose to implement convolution with 3 1D FIRs. In the testing stage, I got `UInt*SInt` multiply results instead of `SInt*SInt`. Here is my 1D FIR implemented in Chisel

```scala
class OneDemConvGen(wgh_num:Int=3, ipt_wid:Int = 8, wgh_wid:Int=8, psum_wid:Int=32) extends Module{
  val io = IO(new Bundle() {
    val in = Input(SInt(ipt_wid.W))
    val weights = Input(Vec(wgh_num, SInt(wgh_wid.W)))

    val psum = Output(SInt(psum_wid.W))
  })

  val muls = Seq.fill(wgh_num)(Wire(SInt(psum_wid.W))).zip(io.weights).map({case (p, w) => p := io.in*w; p})
  val sum = muls.fold(0.S)((a, b) => RegNext(a+b, 0.S))
  io.psum := sum
}
```

I am testing the DLA, and the 1D fir is instanced as a submodule, I got a completely wrong result.
[Wave of incorrect result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFfC3.png)
As you can see from the figure. the `muls-0 =\= -29 * -58`, the result `-13166 = 227 * -58`, its confusing. However, I got the correct result when I tested the fir independently.
[Wave of incorrect result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbgKk.png)

Comment: I'm having difficulty reproducing your results. Can you provide the chisel version you are using and maybe a small example chiseltest style harness

Comment: Can you provide a simplified module that wraps this submodule.  I could not reproduce the error (as you said, direct testing seems to work find)

Comment: Sorry, I just see your comments. It's a strange problem. In my top design, the test data was generated by two memories, weights, and features. I initiated the two memories before testing by function `loadMemoryFromFileInline`. I solved the issue after I change the data type of memory to UInt and cast the output of the memory to SInt. My chisel version is `3.5.5`